# How to identify if an account has Forge Credits available

Tags: autodesk-forge

If I am making Forge API calls on behalf of a customer is there a way to check if the customer has available credits prior to making a call that would consume credits?

Additionally, if I am out of credits will calls to OAuth fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API to return the available credits the customer have.

That said, authenticating does not consume credits, so no, it will not fail. Your customer will pay for Translation services using Model Derivative API, Processing hour using Design Automation API & gigapixel process using Reality Capture API.

Here you can find more detail about Autodesk Forge Pricing.

https://forge.autodesk.com/pricing

Comment: Follow up, if a customer is out of credits are they still free to use the viewer to view previously translated documents? Say they translate all of their documents up front and no longer have a need for credits what prevents them from continuing to use the viewer freely?

Comment: As long they keep having a subscription running they should not need credits to visualize models. The use of the Viewer is free, so already Translated files can be view as much as they want at no cost.